# Prove: For full rank matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ with $m>n$ and diagonal matrix $B\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ we have $rank(ABA^H)=n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, hermitian-matrices, linear-independence

For full rank matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ with $m>n$ and diagonal matrix $B\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ with $det(B)\ne0$ how can we prove that $rank(ABA^H)=n$?

I have already proven that $rank(AB)=n$ and that $(A^HA)^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ are defined.  These properties are easy enough to show.  It is also clear that the column rank of $AB$ and the row rank of $A$ are equal.  I also have a hunch that $ABA^H$ is Hermitian, but I haven't proven this.

I cannot see how to put any of these facts together to prove that $rank(ABA^H)=n$.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should probably say that $det(B) \neq 0$

Comment: Excellent point thank you!

Comment: How about starting by showing that $rank(A A^H ) = n$? (that might not help, I am still thinking about the solution myself)

Comment: hint: $A$ is injective so it has a left inverse $\implies$  $A^H$ has a right inverse...

Comment: @RaoulLuqué So since I have shown that $(A^HA)^{-1}$ exists, I know that $A^HA$ is full rank, and therefore that $rank(A^HA)=n$, I didn't show this proof in the question but if you think it would be helpful I will add it.  I'm not sure how this helps with the rank of $ABA^H$ though?

Comment: @Squid49134 Try using the hint in my answer

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez my apologies I am new to StackExchange and am still learning the do's and dont's, I will put the full question in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of an indirect solution but one might go with the following:

Hint first: Try multiplying matrices from the right and left to $ABA^H$ and then look at the resulting rank.

Solution:

> Consider the Matrix $A^H A B A^H A$. Since $A^H A$ is invertible, $A^H A B A^H A = (A^H A) B (A^H A)$ is invertible and as such of $rank$ $n$.
>  Now suppose that $rank(A B A^H) < n$. In that case $dim(image(A B A^H)) < n$ and as such $dim(image( (A)(A B A^H)(B))) < n$. This would be a contradiction to $A^H A B A^H A$ being invertible. As such the proof is concluded

Comment: While $A^HA$ is invertible, I don't think $AA^H$ is, since $AA^H$ is $m\times m$ but cannot have rank greater than $n$ and I have defined $m>n$

Comment: @Squid49134 Of course, sorry. That you shouldn't be necessary for the prove anyways

Comment: I'm sorry I don't fully understand.  I understand that $A^HABA^HA$ is invertible, and I understand that it therefore has rank n.  I also understand that the rank of the product of matrices must be less than or equal to the rank of the individual matrices, so we know that $rank(ABA^H)\le n$ and therefore if we can show a contradiction in the assumption that $rank(ABA^H)<n$ the proof is complete.  But I don't understand how $dim(image(ABA^H))<n$ implies that $dim(image((A)(ABA^H)(B)))<n$ nor do I understand how this is a contradiction to invertibility of $A^HABA^HA$? Thanks!

Comment: @Squid49134 Okay. So another way of looking at this with your understanding would be: You know that the rank of the product of matrices must be less than or equal to the rank of the individual matrices. So if $rank(ABA^H) < n$ then $rank(A^H (ABA^H) A) < n$. This would be a contradiction to the invertibility of $A^H A B A^H A$ since invertibility implies full rank (which would be $n$ here).

Comment: This makes much more sense.  Thank you SO much I have been agonizing over this for an embarrassingly long time XD.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in\mathbb{C}^m$ and $ABA^H x = 0$, then $x^H ABA^H x = 0$, so $(B^{\frac12}A^Hx)^2 = 0$, where we used the fact that in complex domain, the square root of any diagonal matrices exist. Starting from there, try to show the left null space of $ABA^H$ is a subspace of left null space of $AB^{\frac12}$, so $rank(ABA^H)\ge rank(AB^{\frac12}) = n$. The rest is easy.

Answer (score 0):

We can actually prove a stronger statement directly, namely that $\text{Col}(A)=\text{Col}(ABA^H)$.

Clearly we have $\text{Col}(ABA^H)\subseteq \text{Col}(A)$ so it really only suffices to show that $\text{Col}(ABA^H)\supseteq \text{Col}(A)$.

Choose $y\in \text{Col}(A)$ arbitrarily, then find $x\in \mathbb{C}^n $ such that $y=Ax$.

Since $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(A^H)=n$ we know the columns of $A^H\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times m}$ span all of $\mathbb{C}^n$, so we may find $v$ such that $A^Hv=B^{-1}x$. Evidently, $BA^Hv=x$ and so $ABA^Hv=Ax=y$ which shows $y\in \text{Col}(ABA^H)$ as required.